# Is synchronization required inside a controller method that reads and writes to an SQLite database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

So between the `FirstOrDefaultAsync` call and `SaveChangesAsync()`, is it possible another invocation of the controller from another user causes issues?

Is it necessary to use `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` or similar methods to lock the resource(database)?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Updates a project's Name and/or SlackWebHookUrl.
    /// </summary>
    [HttpPut("{projectId}")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProject(int projectId, [FromBody] Project projectToEdit)
    {
        Project project = await _databaseContext.Projects
            .Where(p => p.Id == projectId)
            .Include(p => p.LockedFiles)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if (project == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"No matching project found with id: {projectId}");
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(projectToEdit.Name))
        {
            project.Name = projectToEdit.Name;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(projectToEdit.SlackWebHookUrl))
        {
            project.SlackWebHookUrl = projectToEdit.SlackWebHookUrl;
        }

        await _databaseContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(project);
    }
```

Comment: Synchronization is an issue even if you used a full-featured RDBMS like SQL Server or Oracle. The solution to that, for the last 30 years, is to use optimistic concurrency, not locks and transactions. *Especially* in web sites, where multiple requests can come at any time

Comment: Using transactions like the first client/server applications did 30 years ago is *not* a solution. You end up with blocking and long delays even with a few concurrent requests.

Comment: Thank you. Reading on optimistic concurrency.